A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?
The question is: According to Roman Catholicism, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the RC definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
I apologize for the phrasing of the 'title'.  The original was being wrongly resisted as a duplicate by the bot.
Related: According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?, What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?, What is the Methodist position on God's soul?, Do Baptists say God has a soul?, Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?, Do Anglicans think God has a soul?, Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?

No. God does not have a soul in Catholic theology. There are two parts to the reason why.

Divine Simplicity. Because God is simple (lacking all composition), anything we might informally speak of God possessing as far as an attribute goes is the divine essence itself. In this regard, God's intellect is God himself (the Divine essence), not a soul.

A soul is the animating principle; that is, the soul is what gives life to the material body. In this sense, animals have a soul (not an immortal rational one). God in contrast is pure spirit with no matter to animate. In this regard, angels are more similar to God than to humans.


A human soul is uniquely both soul (animating principle/form of material body) and spirit (non-corporeal, immortal intellectual substance). Similar to animals, a man's soul gives life to his body. Similar to angels, his soul is capable of intelligence and incorruptible. The Council of Vienne (1311) defined as an article of faith that "the rational soul, which is one with the sensitive and vegetative principle, is the form of the body" Catholic Encyclopedia on Soul. "Form" is the Aristotelian counterpart to "Matter" in the context of substances.
